3d lines cut below and above a surface (ground)
I have dgn and dxf formatted CAD 3D lines which are "cables" below the ground. These cables are sometimes 1m below ground and sometimes 50cm and 10cm etc., below the ground. I have pointcloud LAS data as ground elevation data.
Now I want to extract the cables(lines) which are below the ground upto 50cm. I want to cut the cables layer with elevation model to selct the cables network from 0 to 50 cm below the ground.
How can I cut those lines? I am trying with qgis and FME but, unable to get the right solution. Anyone has idea what software or methods to follow.
